# How to return html element from object

Tags: reactjs

I've created function which returns me drawed photo. I'm trying to assign it as an img url, but instead of html element it returns me an object. How can I refer to an html element instead of to object?

This is function that returns me an image:

```
function workoutImage() {
  const images = [
    {
      img1: "./images/workout-image1.jpg",
    },
    {
      img2: "./images/workout-image2.jpg",
    },
    {
      img3: "./images/workout-image3.jpg",
    },
  ];

  const imageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  let returnImage = images[imageIndex];

  return returnImage;
}

export default workoutImage;
```

and here's component where I'm trying to display it:

```
function WorkoutsDiary() {

  let workoutImage = workoutImageDraw();

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        {showWorkouts &&
          showWorkouts.map((workout, key) => (
            <Image key={key}>
              <Link to={`/exercise/` + workout.id}>
                <img src={workoutImage} alt="" />
              </Link>
            </Image>
          ))}
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

when I do a console log, it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
return returnImage;
```

is returning an instance of an object.  For example, this:

```
{
  img1: "./images/workout-image1.jpg",
}
```

If you just want it to return the string property on that object, return that property:

```
return returnImage.img1;
```

**Alternatively**, if you want to return the whole object then just use its string property in the attribute value:

```
<img src={workoutImage.img1} alt="" />
```

---

**Edit:** I just noticed that your objects *all have different property names* so you'd need to determine which one to use.  Instead, I would recommend having a single common object structure.  Or forget the objects entirely and just use an array of strings:

```
const images = [
  "./images/workout-image1.jpg",
  "./images/workout-image2.jpg",
  "./images/workout-image3.jpg",
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of objects, and you have different keys in each of the objects.

It should be array of strings.

```
const images = [
  "./images/workout-image1.jpg",
  "./images/workout-image2.jpg",
  "./images/workout-image3.jpg"
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is modify your `workoutImage` in this way:

```
function workoutImage() {
  const images = [
    "./images/workout-image1.jpg",
    "./images/workout-image2.jpg",
    "./images/workout-image3.jpg",
  ];

  const imageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  let returnImage = images[imageIndex];

  return returnImage;
}

export default workoutImage;
```

Now you should see your image in `img`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import img from workoutImage
```

and use image like this

```
 <img src={img} alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
let returnImage = images[imageIndex];
```

To :

```
    let returnImage = '';
Object.keys(images[imageIndex]).map((key) => {
  returnImage = images[imageIndex][key]
});
```